# Matlab solution of an equation as a Matrix

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, equation

I got an equation S with 2 variables h and k. Now iwant to aquire the solution of this as a 11x11 matrix with values from 1 to 10 for h and k.
So the matrix should include every solution in this format:

S(0,0) S(1,0) S(3,0) S (4,0)
S(0,1) S(1,1) S(3,1) S (4,1)
S(0,2) S(1,2) S(3,2) S (4,2)
S(0,3) S(1,3) S(3,3) S (4,3)  etc.I thin you get what i mean.

Is this somehow possible with matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example I would go for the easies solution, which is using `for` loops:

```
output = zeros(11, 11);
for ii = 0:10
    for jj = 0:10
        output(ii, jj) = S(ii, jj);
    end
end
```

Unless you are facing a difficulty which is not included in your example.

Comment: Thanks! I never worked with for loops before...how do i get my output here? i designed a function S and got the results simply by typing s(1,0) for example. Where do i have to ad the loop?

Comment: You can either write your code as a matlab [`script`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-scripts.html) and run it, or simply type each line in the Command Window. Afterwards, you will have the result you want in `output`. To see it, type `output` in Command Window and press enter.